# Wrong type argument: proper-list-p in Flymake example

Tags: require, flymake

I'm implementing my own Flymake backend while following the annotated example from the Emacs manual: [GNU Flymake 1.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/flymake.html#An-annotated-example-backend). What I've implemented works perfectly within Emacs, however, when I try to `batch-byte-compile` it, I run into the following error:

```shell
emacs -batch -L . -f batch-byte-compile my-backend.el

In toplevel form:
my-backend.el:28:2: Error: Wrong type argument: proper-list-p, (beg . end)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Pointing to the following code in the annotated example:

```el
(cl-loop
 while (search-forward-regexp ... )
 for msg = (match-string 2)

 ;; This is the offending line
 for (beg . end) = (flymake-diag-region
                    source
                    (string-to-number (match-string 1)))

 for type = (if (string-match "^warning" msg)
                :warning
              :error)
 collect (flymake-make-diagnostic source beg end type msg)
 into diags
 finally (funcall report-fn diags))
```

Trying to change the assignment of beg/end to some other list form (e.g. `(list ...)` or `(beg end)` or `'(beg end)`, and so on) satisfies the byte compile error, but causes the program to fail.

What am I missing here? How can I change the arguments to satisfy `batch-byte-compile`, and why is the error being raised in the first place?

Comment: The annotated example is missing a `(require 'cl-lib)`: they probably never tried compiling it. Please submit a documentation bug report (although I don't know where: if worse comes to worst, try `M-x report-emacs-bug` and see if they send you somewhere else).

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I’ll look into reporting it upstream.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info